# Is it possible to inherit the environment context of a called composite GitHub action in the caller workflow

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, workflow

I have the following composite action;

```yaml
name: Send Email 
description: Use this composite action
# outputs:
#   key_value_x: 
#     value: ${{ env.testvarenv }} 
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - name: set environment variable
    run: |
      echo "testvarenv='wow'" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
    shell: powershell
  - name: Inside composite action
    run: |
      echo "testvarenv is ${{ env.testvarenv }}"
    shell: powershell
```

The `testvarenv` prints fine inside the composite action.

However, when I try to print the same in the caller workflow (outside the composite workflow) it does not print the value of `${{ env.testvarenv }}`

```yaml
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use the composite action in the root dir
      uses: ./
    - name: Outside composite action      
      run: |
        echo "testvarenv is ${{ env.testvarenv }}"
```

I'm aware how to use `outputs:` to get the value of any composite variable outside i.e. in the caller workflow; but wanted to know if it is possible to use `environment` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit to correct the answer:**

Not sure why OP's saying that their example didn't work. You can repro it and it'll work.

[The docs for composite actions's `runs.steps[*].env` field](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsenv) state that;

> If you want to modify the environment variable stored in the workflow, use echo `"{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV` in a composite step.

You can repro with linux **action** `SO/76522542/nix/action.yml`

```yaml
name: Set Env Value
description: Use this composite action
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - name: set environment variable
    run: echo "ENVWORD=abcxyz" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    shell: bash
  - name: Inside composite action
    run: echo "ENVWORD is ${{ env.ENVWORD }}"
    shell: bash
```

Windows **action** `SO/76522542/win/action.yml` (as OP used `powershell` which is windows runner exclusive, unlike `pwsh`)

```yaml
name: Set Env Value
description: Use this composite action
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
  - name: set environment variable
    run: echo "ENVWORD='abcxyz'" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV
    shell: powershell
  - name: Inside composite action
    run: echo "ENVWORD is ${{ env.ENVWORD }}"
    shell: powershell
```

And **workflow** `.github/workflows/76522542.yml`

```yaml
name: SO 76522542 - Env example
on:
  push:
jobs:
  linux-action-env-example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use the composite action
      uses: ./SO/76522542/nix
    - name: Outside composite action      
      run: echo "ENVWORD is ${{ env.ENVWORD }}"
  windows-action-env-example:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: powershell
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use the composite action
      uses: ./SO/76522542/win
    - name: Outside composite action      
      run: |
        echo "ENVWORD is ${{ env.ENVWORD }}"
```

[This appears to have always been the case per the docs (at least 4 years ago)](https://github.com/github/docs/blame/c478c1ecd9d91aa5d0c93eae2a0791813d116cf5/content/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions.md#L245-L247).

**Original Answer:** (that was for `worfklows`, and is wrong for `actions`)

See [Reusing workflows: Limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) for;

> Similarly, environment variables set in the `env` context, defined in the called workflow, are not accessible in the `env` context of the caller workflow.

Comment: This is useful, but does not answer the question. The question is about workflow using a composite action. Not a workflow calling a workflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @TWiStErRob -- my bad, I guess I sped through this one and should have been more careful. Updated it (which indeed changes the tldr answer from `no` to `yes`, so thanks for pointing this one out).